# How to get a List of directories and files from a URL Android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to get a list of directory and files in ListView in Android

For the sdcard  I use this code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



    // list.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
    // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to))
    /*
     * File root = new File(Environment .getExternalStorageDirectory()
     * .getAbsolutePath());
     */
    File root = new File("sdcard");
    ListDir(root);

}

void ListDir(File f) {
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    fileList.clear();
    for (File file : files) {
        fileList.add(file.getPath());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    setListAdapter(directoryList);
}
```

I want show a list from an  URL uri ="http://192.168.10.225/".

Comment: How to Request with Json for Getting List directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a directory behind an URL like a local directory. You will need to enable DirectoryListing in your webserver configuration and then parse the HTML page provided by the webserver when the URL is accessed. You could use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to load the website then.

Comment: i can use in webview and listing directory is ok.

Comment: but i want listing in listview... any way  do it?

Comment: you will need to parse the HTML you receive from the webserver. You could rotate through every line and look for links. if you want to do it nicely see if you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html or one of the Java HTML parsers here: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Comment: How to Request with Json for Getting List directory ?

Comment: there won't be anything that returns you a listview or JSON string out of thin air. if you're going to request HTML via HTTP, you will receive HTML and have to format it yourself.

Comment: the directory now is configured for http,not problem... I try works in json for getting list

Comment: how to use in regex to find tag <a> and list items in listview?

Comment: String html = "foo <a href='link1'>bar</a> baz <a href='link2'>qux</a> foo";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href='(.*?)'>");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

  try {
   while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    list.add(m.group(1));

   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }

  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
  lst.setAdapter(dataAdapter);